# What if I use Flutter master channel for production app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Right now I am using Flutter stable channel for my Android and iOS production app. At this time Flutter web is not available on the stable channel and I also want my existing app for the web.

So, will there be any type of issue with my existing app if I use the Flutter master channel?

(Here's I know that Flutter web is also available in the beta channel but I want to switch to master channel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are recommended to stick with the stable channel for production applications, although the beta channel is the next best option if you are looking to make a web application with Flutter. Switching to master has some inherent risks that you should consider before switching. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels.

Why exactly would you like to be on the master channel? It is not very safe, especially when you can wait a little while for the changes to trickle down to dev and beta.